# Youtube Video still playing in background after attempt to close it by clicking on the overlay area (Colorbox module used)

Tags: views, files, modal-dialogs

I created a Youtube video gallery using **video embedded field module** (to put my Youtube url) and **colorbox module** to create a nice overlay pop up.

I have created the gallery grid with the Views module. Everything works perfectly on all browsers, except Internet Explorer >= 8.

When I try to close the video by clicking on the overlay area or the close button, the video closes, but its sound keeps playing on the background.

Do you have any idea about why it does this on Internet Explorer?

Comment: Probably worth submitting a bug report to [Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/project/issues/video_embed_field?categories=bug), I couldn't find anything similar already reported.

Comment: Thank you it's done. I'm very surprised this issue hasn't been reported by anyone.